# In Express.js, why does my downloaded file have a different size to the server file size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My express.js code is very simple:

```
app.get("/download", download);
```

and

```
export let download = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const file = "/tmp/my-file.zip";
  res.download(file);
}
```

My client code is also straightforward:

```
import axios from "axios";
const fileDownload = require("js-file-download");

axios.get("/download").then(response => {
  fileDownload(response.data, "export.zip");
});
```

When downloaded from the browser, the file is corrupt and I can't open it. The original `/tmp/my-file.zip` is `119506` bytes. Strangely, the downloaded `export.zip` is `216980` bytes. I'm running everything locally at the moment so there are not operating system differences that would explain this.

Why are my file sizes different (leading to a corrupt .zip file) and how do I fix this?

Edit - these are the browser headers:

```
accept-ranges: "bytes"
cache-control: "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
connection: "keep-alive"
content-disposition: "attachment; filename="my-file.zip""
content-length: "119506"
content-type: "application/zip"
date: "Thu, 14 Mar 2019 06:04:28 GMT"
etag: "W/"1d2d2-1697acd3f53""
expires: "0"
last-modified: "Thu, 14 Mar 2019 06:04:25 GMT"
pragma: "no-cache"
referrer-policy: "no-referrer"
surrogate-control: "no-store"
x-content-type-options: "nosniff"
x-frame-options: "SAMEORIGIN"
x-xss-protection: "1; mode=block"
```

Comment: What type of response you are getting back is it a json?

Comment: I've edited my question to include browser headers. It should be a zip file based on content-type.

Comment: What happens if you just navigate with your browser to `/download`?

Comment: @felixmosh good test and that works fine. I guess that axios or js-file-download is something altering the file.

Comment: So why do you want to use it via ajax?
Just put a link with `download` attribute on it, it will download the file :]

Comment: @felixmosh good point but I've simplified my example somewhat. My actual code has dynamic parameters based on what the user selects and so that's why I chose an AJAX approach. But you've given me a big clue so maybe I can find the solution from there. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to download with other file types? Like .json, .txt, .doc. Make sure all file types happen or the only file.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution at this [post](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3636#issuecomment-385047089). Because [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) responseType default is json

> // `responseType` indicates the type of data that the server will
>   respond with   // options are 'arraybuffer', 'blob', 'document',
>   'json', 'text', 'stream'   responseType: 'json', // default

```
axios.get('/download',{ responseType:'arraybuffer'})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('########### HEADERS: ', response.headers);
    console.log('########### AXIOS: ', response.data.length);
  fileDownload(response.data, "export.zip");
});
```

Hope it works :)